# aws-amplify signout from federatedSignIn

Tags: amazon-web-services, federated-identity, aws-amplify

I am using google federated sign-in with aws-amplify. Sign-In works as expected, but when i use Auth.SignOut(), it throws an exception "Not Authenticated".

Is there a different method I should be using to signout from federated sign in ? Or is there a workaround which I can use to signout from aws-amplify ?